# Android: Can I get the OS's last played audio/video or viewed image from inside my application?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Android developers,

I would like to know if it is possible to get, from inside my application, a reference to the last played media (audio or video) or viewed image.

I tried to get a list of MediaPlayer, but all I can get is the MediaPlayer from my own application context, not from the other applications. I could also get the current state for the MediaPlayer (if a file is playing or not), but thas all.

Is this possible?

thanks and regards

Comment: For files which you can access, you can use a FileObserver to detect when others are accessing them, but it may take some cleverness to determine that this access is specifically a playing.  Note that doing this for a lot of directories starts to get expensive.  I don't think you can do this for files in directories which you can't access, such as is the default for another app's private storage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. For security reasons, an app cannot just view another app's data and there is no global 'recents' list (as in windows).